# Disable Autolayout Warning in debug console ONLY for one particular framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, ios-autolayout, suppress-warnings

I have a third party framework with a view that generates a "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." warning in the debug console. I want to disable this warning only for that particular framework. I would like other classes in my project to raise Autolayout warnings. Thanks.